# 1С Переменная не определена

Tags: 1с

Недавно начала познавать 1с, так что не ругайте за очень глупые ошибки. Задача загрузить файл excel. В процессе столкнулась с ошибкой и уже очень долго сижу и не знаю что и как
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что исправить, а то не доходит :(

Ошибка: "{Документ.ЗагрузкаДанных.Форма.ФормаДокумента.Форма(62,3)}: Переменная не определена (НоваяСтрока)
<<?>>НоваяСтрока.ПоказателиАртикул = Товар.Артикул; (Проверка: Сервер)"

Код:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ЗагрузкаДанных(Команда)
    //ЗагрузкаДанныхНаСервере();
    ТабДок = ЗагрузкаДанныхНаСервереОтладка();
    ТабДок.Показать();
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Процедура ЗагрузкаДанныхНаСервере()
    ТабличныйДокумент = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;
    ТабличныйДокумент.Прочитать("C:\1311.xlsx", СпособЧтенияЗначенийТабличногоДокумента.Значение);
    Для А = 3 По ТабличныйДокумент.ВысотаТаблицы Цикл
        НаименованиеТовара = ТабличныйДокумент.Область("R" + А + "C2").Текст;
        АртикулТовара = ТабличныйДокумент.Область("R" + А + "C1").Текст;
        ЦенаТовара = ТабличныйДокумент.Область("R" + А + "C3").Текст; 
        Товар = Справочники.Товар.НайтиПоНаименованию(НаименованиеТовара);
        Если Товар.Пустая() Тогда
            ТоварОбъект = Справочники.Товар.СоздатьЭлемент();  
            ТоварОбъект.Наименование = НаименованиеТовара; 
            Артикул = Справочники.Товар.НайтиПоРеквизиту("Артикул", АртикулТовара);
            Если Артикул.Пустая() Тогда 
                АртикулОбъект = Справочники.Товар.СоздатьЭлемент();
                АртикулОбъект.Наименование = НаименованиеТовара;
                АртикулОбъект.Артикул = АртикулТовара;
                АртикулОбъект.Записать();
                Артикул = АртикулОбъект.Ссылка;
            КонецЕсли;
            ТоварОбъект.Артикул = Артикул;
            ТоварОбъект.Записать();
            Товар = ТоварОбъект.Ссылка;
        КонецЕсли;     
        НоваяСторка = Объект.Показатели.Добавить();
        НоваяСторка.ПоказателиТовар = Товар;
        НоваяСтрока.ПоказателиАртикул = Товар.Артикул;   
    КонецЦикла;
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Функция ЗагрузкаДанныхНаСервереОтладка() 
    ТабличныйДокумент = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;
    ТабличныйДокумент.Прочитать("C:\1311.xlsx", СпособЧтенияЗначенийТабличногоДокумента.Значение);
    Возврат ТабличныйДокумент;
КонецФункции
```

Answer (score 1):

Новая**Стор**ка = Объект.Показатели.Добавить();

Новая**Стро**ка.ПоказателиАртикул = Товар.Артикул;

Comment: Тоже буквально сейчас обнаружила, спасибо)